# ASP.NET WebApi specify action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I need to create ASP.NET WebApi with couple operation, for example RegisterAppStart, RegisterStep and RegisterAppEnd. And I want to place all this actions in one controller. As I read, usually in WebApi action name is not using.
And my question - is this a bad idea to rewrite default route config with actions using?

ps. sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give actions arbitrary names using the `[Route("/api/FooController/BarMethod"]` attribute routing.

This usually overrides the "REST"yness of your service (where the request method indicates which method should be called), but as you aren't really building a REST service, you shouldn't care.